# Extracting attributes of elements XML with different numbers of children

Tags: sql-server, xml, nodes

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<locations>
    <loc loc_id="11703">
        <height type="low">22.19</height>
        <height type="high">24.19</height>
    </loc>
    <loc loc_id="11702">
        <height type="low">22.95</height>
    </loc>
    <loc loc_id="11702">
        <height type="mid">24.4</height>
    </loc>
    <loc loc_id="11702">
        <height type="high">24.95</height>
    </loc>
    <loc loc_id="11701">
        <height type="low">17.65</height>
        <height type="mid">23.99</height>
    </loc>
    <loc loc_id="11700">
        <height type="low">21.49</height>
        <height type="high">23.45</height>
        <height type="mid">23.3</height>
    </loc>
    <loc loc_id="11699">
        <height type="low">21.65</height>
        <height type="high">24.14</height>
    </loc>
</locations>
```

And I'm trying to select all the heights of elements, but I'm getting the same height when the node has 2 or 3 child

```
DECLARE @xmlDataHeights XML

SET @xmlDataHeights = (
  SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK 'C:\heights (6).xml', SINGLE_CLOB
  ) AS xmlData
)
SELECT
    ref.value('../@loc_id[1]', 'int') AS LocID ,
    ref.value('@type[1]', 'NVARCHAR (50)') AS type,
    ref.value('../height[1]', 'NVARCHAR (50)') AS height
FROM 
    @xmlDataHeights.nodes('/locations/loc/height') xmlData(ref)
WHERE
    ref.value('../@place_id[1]', 'int') = 11703
```

In the example above I try to get the heights of the location 11703 but it repeats the first value for the high and low type

**Current result**:

```
LocID   type    height
----------------------
11703   low     22.19
11703   high    22.19
```

What should returned:

```
LocID   type    height
----------------------
11703   low     22.19
11703   high    24.19
```

Comment: Please at least make sure that your sample data and query *match*, execute and actually produce the result set that you claim. Asking about code that *you yourself* have never run tends to be problematic.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why you mention it, I've been trying to get the result for a while and I know more or less where the error is ... but I can't solve it, I know that if I change the height predicate to value 2 (height[2]) n the SELECT clause, it brings me the other value that I'm missing of the height but I would also duplicate it in both types (low and high)

Comment: No, you haven't run the code in the question or you'd have spotted you forgot to replace `place_id` with `loc_id` in the `WHERE` clause. So you're showing us something *close to* the code that you're running but you've not done us the courtesy of ensuring that the actual code you're showing us produces the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much Damien_The_Unbeliever, I already saw the error in the where clause, an apology.
I'm not very familiar with XPath expressions I'm not a programmer but I try to learn and make my job easier

Comment: You can [edit] your question to correct any issues at any time - given its going to stay here forever I would recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really spend some time familiarizing yourself with XPath expressions. In your `FROM` clause you're extracting the `height` elements and then in a number of places you're using the parent axis (`..`) to move up to the enclosing `loc` elements - but you don't want to do that to retrieve the value of the current `height` element - just stay right there:

```
SELECT
    ref.value('../@loc_id[1]', 'int') AS LocID ,
    ref.value('@type[1]', 'NVARCHAR (50)') AS type,
    ref.value('.', 'NVARCHAR (50)') AS height
FROM 
    @xmlDataHeights.nodes('/locations/loc/height') xmlData(ref)
WHERE
    ref.value('../@loc_id[1]', 'int') = 11703
```

Produces:

```
LocID       type       height
----------- ---------- ------------
11703       low        22.19
11703       high       24.19
```

(Note that I also had to correct the `WHERE` clause because you gave us an untested query)